# Adding a static route for gmail?

Tags: windows-7, networking, routing, static-routes

I have my PC (windows7) on two networks - WiFi Hotspot and LAN at the same time.
I would like to add a route on my PC such that requests to gmail go to the Wifi Hotspot and everything else to LAN proxy (everything goes to LAN proxy now).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried "route add" command?

Comment: I know that I have to use route command. But, the question is, what would I add for gmail? I believe for gmail, dns resolution will be attempted first. So, does this mean, I have to add a route to a diff dns server?

Comment: Emmm I get your point but I have no idea...